# I used the 'dd' command to put a Linux image onto a flash drive, and it changed the flash drive's properties. How can I undo it?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

When I dd'd the image onto the flash drive, somehow it changed it from an 8GB flash to 859MB. I don't know what I did wrong, but I don't really need to. I booted from a different flash drive.

The issue is that now that I've erased everything off of the flash drive, it has remained 859 MB with 4 unremovable partitions. Last time, I changed the file system of the flash from my windows PC and it eradicated the partitions and reset the flash drive, but I don't remember what I did.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't handle multiple partitions on removeable USB drives very well.  Clearing the partition table entirely and reformatting is the easiest.

You can clear the partition table with `diskpart` `CLEAN`, referenced [here](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-Diskpart-to-create-extend-or-delete-a-disk-partition).

> At a command prompt, type: Diskpart.exe
>
> At the DISKPART prompt, type: `SELECT DISK X`

Make sure you select the right disk.  Use `LIST DISK` to see and check against your flash drive's capacity and double check the drive letters.

> At the DISKPART prompt, type: `CLEAN ALL` (The CLEAN ALL command removes all partition and volume information from the hard drive being focused on.)
>
> At the DISKPART prompt, type: `EXIT`